# C++ and Octave results differ for simple arithmetic

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, octave, pow

I have a C++ code and an Octave that both compute the same equation

In C++

```
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 1.5f;
    float y = pow(x, 6) * 235809835.41f - pow(x, 5) * 2110439254.2f + pow(x, 4) *7869448124.8f - pow(x, 3) * 15648965509.0f + pow(x, 2) * 17503313074.0f - (x)* 10440563329.0f + 2594694745.0f; // result y = 3584
    return 0;
}
```

In Octave

```
x = 1.5
y = (x ^ 6) * 235809835.41 - (x ^ 5) * 2110439254.2 + (x ^ 4) *7869448124.8 - (x ^ 3) * 15648965509 + (x ^ 2) * 17503313074 - (x)* 10440563329 + 2594694745‏ // result y = 26
```

The computed value of y differs in the two cases. C++ computes y to be 3584 and Octave computes y to be 26. What could be the cause for this divergence?

EDIT : Excel produces the same result as Octave, and the result is logical too within the context of the equation. So, something is wrong with the C++ code or compiler.

Comment: FWIW, Maxima shows the result to be 26.81078290939331. Not sure what rounding Octave is doing...

Comment: Most probably you will have a significant loss of precision in C++ due to cancellation while Octave might either calculate with extended precision or it rearranges the order of the operations.

Comment: octave 3.8.2 gives 26.811, as it should be. Did you round off to the lowest value ?

Comment: A constant like 235809835.41f does not make sense (the compiler should emit a warning). In single precision floating-point (float), the significand has a precision of 24 bits, about 7 decimal digits. Use double precision (double, no f suffix). Your expression is also pretty ill-conditioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be due to the limited precision of the `float` type, which is likely causing one of the operations to be effectively discarded because one operand is of a smaller enough magnitude than the other to cause a significant change to the result.  (See [this extremely contrived example](http://ideone.com/bT4OMO) that shows what this might look like.)

If you rewrite the code to use the `double` type, which is more precise, then [the result is 26.810783](http://ideone.com/71Pshs), which matches the result I get from evaluating the formula in Maxima.

Further reading: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)